# write a dictionary of different-length lists to a csv file

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a dictionary of lists to a csv file. The solution in:[Write dictionary of lists to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613426/write-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

will trim longer lists. For example if I want to write the following:

```
d = {"key1": [1, 2, 3], "key2": [4, 5, 6], "key3": [7, 8, 9, 11]}
with open("test.csv", "wb") as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(d.keys())
writer.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

The results is

```
key3   key2  key1
7      4     1
8      5    2
9      6    3
```

11 is deleted from key3. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a loop instead of writerows+zip

Comment: I tried but couldn't get what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy answer is to use `itertools.izip_longest` instead of `zip`

```
import itertools
import csv

d = {"key1": [1, 2, 3], "key2": [4, 5, 6], "key3": [7, 8, 9, 11]}
with open("test.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(d.keys())
    writer.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(*d.values()))
```