# Export Dictionary with Lists to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, web-scraping

EDIT: in my attempt to narrow down my question I may have oversimplified in a way that makes it harder to answer.  Let me try again.  Assume that the dictionary is:

```
holder = {'key1':['headline1', 'body1'], 'key2':['headline2', 'body2']}
```

I'm looking to output that dictionary to a csv file that will represent that information in three columns: the key column, the headline column, and the body column.  Trying to do that with the answer noted below failed for the reasons noted below.

Hopefully that's a bit more clear.

---

I'm scraping some chinese news sites and trying to output the results into a csv file.  After scraping, the dictionary is structured:

```
uniqueID : [headlines, body]
```

for each story.  I'm trying to output to a CSV that ultimately reads:

```
uniqueID1 / headlines1 / body1
uniqueID2 / headlines2 / body2
uniqueID3 / headlines3 / body3
```

with each of those in a different column (so basically three columns with as many rows as I have stories).

I tried using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613426/write-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-file) but, in addition to flipping the X and Y axis (which I know how to fix), it also broke out each character in each headline/story into a different entry and broke the character encoding.  Since I don't know how to fix either of those problems I'm a bit stuck.

If it is helpful or relevant, I'm encoding the characters this way:

```
head_fixed = str(headline)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(head_fixed, 'lxml')
    good_output = soup.text.decode("unicode-escape").encode("utf-8")
```

Naturally, I'm also open to the suggestion that the way that I'm structuring the data is wrong.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Can you show the whole code or at least a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's incredibility difficult for anybody to test their solutions or even really understand your problem without it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is too vague.

Comment: Where are the unique IDs coming from? How are you getting the headlines vs the story bodies? Do you really think using `/` a delimiter for your csv file is a good idea - what if the story or body has that character in it?

Comment: sorry, clearly over simplified.  I edited the question above, hopefully it is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with [`pandas`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/) (you may need to `pip install pandas`):

```
import pandas as pd

holder = {'key1':['headline1', 'body1'], 'key2':['headline2', 'body2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(holder)

df.transpose().to_csv('output.csv', header=None)

# output.csv:
# key1  headline1  body1
# key2  headline2  body2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by restructuring the data as a list, so:

```
holder = [[key1, headline1, body1], [key2, headline2, body2]]
```

Then I just used

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(holder)
```

I am not sure if there is an advantage to using dictionaries, lists, or combinations of the two in this sort of situation.  In this case switching to a list seemed to work, although I am a bit curious about the solution suggested by Daniel.

Comment: Glad to see you solved it.  Just FYI: it's better practice on Stackoverflow to vote up or accept answers that help out, rather than submitting an answer of your own :)  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  As is clear by everything in this question, I'm still learning my way around the site (and python....)

Comment: It's all good.  You should be able to vote up and accept answers: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers