# How to write a dictionary of lists to a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have this dictionary of lists that I want to write it in a CSV file:

```
file2_Dict =  {'id': ' ', 'gender': ['M', 'M'], 'name': ['Smith', 'John'], 'city': ['Omaha','Lincoln']}
```

The problem is that not all the keys of the dictionary have a list of items as a value.  In this case the key (i.e.`'id'`) has a string as value (i.e. `" "`).  I tried to use the solution provided by [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613426/write-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-file), but this only outputs the header of the csv file (keys of the dictionary), like this:

```
id, gender, name, city
```

The expected output should be, like this:

```
 id, gender, name, city
  ,M,Smith,Omaha
  ,M,John,Lincoln
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process the dictionary and replace "empty" values with empty lists. Then use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead of `zip()`:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

file2_Dict =  {'id': ' ', 'gender': ['M', 'M'], 'name': ['Smith', 'John'], 'city': ['Omaha','Lincoln']}

# replace space string values with empty lists
for key, value in file2_Dict.items():
    if value == ' ':
        file2_Dict[key] = []

with open("test.csv", "wb") as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerow(file2_Dict.keys())
   writer.writerows(izip_longest(*file2_Dict.values()))
```

Which would produce:

```
gender,city,id,name
M,Omaha,,Smith
M,Lincoln,,John
```

Comment: This is working great, I am looking forward to replicate this functionality into a csv string instead of a csv file. What am I required to change here?