# Pivot a CSV string using python without using pandas or any similar library

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

You may think of this one as another redundant question asked, but I tried to go through all similar questions asked, no luck so far. In my specific use-case, I can't use pandas or any other similar library for this operation.

This is what my input looks like

```
AttributeName,Value
Name,John
Gender,M
PlaceofBirth,Texas
Name,Alexa
Gender,F
SurName,Garden
```

This is my expected output

```
Name,Gender,Surname,PlaceofBirth
John,M,,Texas
Alexa,F,Garden,
```

So far, I have tried to store my input into a dictionary and then tried writing it to a csv string. But, it is failing as I am not sure how to incorporate missing column values conditions. Here is my code so far

```
  reader = csv.reader(csvstring.split('\n'), delimiter=',')

  csvdata = {}
  csvfile = ''
  for row in reader:
    if row[0] != '' and row[0] in csvdata and row[1] != '':
      csvdata[row[0]].append(row[1])
    elif row[0] != '' and row[0] in csvdata and row[1] == '':
      csvdata[row[0]].append(' ')
    elif row[0] != '' and row[1] != '':
      csvdata[row[0]] = [row[1]]
    elif row[0] != '' and row[1] == '':
      csvdata[row[0]] = [' ']
    
  for key, value in csvdata.items():
    if value == ' ':
      csvdata[key] = []

  csvfile += ','.join(csvdata.keys()) + '\n'
  for row in zip(*csvdata.values()):
    csvfile += ','.join(row) + '\n'
```

For the above code as well, I took some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900256/how-to-write-a-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-string). Thanks in advance for any suggestions/advice.

Edit #1 : Update code to imply that I am doing processing on a csv string instead of a csv file.

Comment: is 'Name' mandatory?

Comment: No value in column AttributeName column is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like that:

```
import csv

with open("in.csv") as infile:
    buffer = []
    item = {}

    lines = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] == 'Name':
            buffer.append(item.copy())
            item = {'Name':line[1]}
        else:
            item[line[0]] = line[1]
    buffer.append(item.copy())

for item in buffer[1:]:
    print item
```

Comment: with the buffer[1:] list, you can save it in a csv or whatever

Answer (score 1):

If none of the attributes is mandatory, I think @framontb solution needs to be rearranged in order to work also when `Name` field is not given.
This is an import-free solution, and it's not super elegant.

I assume you have lines already in this form, with this columns:

```
lines = [
    "Name,John",
    "Gender,M",
    "PlaceofBirth,Texas",
    "Gender,F",
    "Name,Alexa",
    "Surname,Garden"  # modified typo here: SurName -> Surname
]

cols = ["Name", "Gender", "Surname", "PlaceofBirth"]
```

We need to distinguish one record from another, and without mandatory fields the best I can do is start considering a new record when an attribute *has already been seen*.
To do this, I use a temporary list of attributes `tempcols` from which I remove elements until an error is raised, i.e. new record.

**Code:**

```
csvdata = {k:[] for k in cols}

tempcols = list(cols)
for line in lines:
    attr, value = line.split(",")
    try:
        csvdata[attr].append(value)
        tempcols.remove(attr)
    except ValueError:
        for c in tempcols:  # now tempcols has only "missing" attributes 
            csvdata[c].append("")
        tempcols = [c for c in cols if c != attr]
for c in tempcols:
    csvdata[c].append("")

# write csv string with the code you provided
csvfile = ""
csvfile += ",".join(csvdata.keys()) + "\n"
for row in zip(*csvdata.values()):
    csvfile += ",".join(row) + "\n"

>>> print(csvfile)
Name,PlaceofBirth,Surname,Gender
John,Texas,,M
Alexa,,Garden,F
```

---

While, if you want to sort columns according to your desired output:

```
csvfile = ""
csvfile += ",".join(cols) + "\n"
for row in zip(*[csvdata[k] for k in cols]):
    csvfile += ",".join(row) + "\n"

>>> print(csvfile)
Name,Gender,Surname,PlaceofBirth
John,M,,Texas
Alexa,F,Garden,
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```py
with open("in.csv") as infile, open("out.csv", "w") as outfile:
    incsv, outcsv = csv.reader(infile), csv.writer(outfile)
    incsv.__next__()  # Skip 1st row
    outcsv.writerows(zip(*incsv))
```

**Update**: For input and output as strings:

```py
import csv, io

with io.StringIO(indata) as infile, io.StringIO() as outfile:
    incsv, outcsv = csv.reader(infile), csv.writer(outfile)
    incsv.__next__()  # Skip 1st row
    outcsv.writerows(zip(*incsv))

    print(outfile.getvalue())
```

Comment: I need to create a csvstring in place of csv file.

Comment: The input csv which I am getting is also in form of csv string and I am not in liberty to use with (open) :(
can we do it just by string manipulations.

Comment: We could use StringIO for the input data too. We *could* do it all ourselves with string functions and a state machine, but it's really awkward. CSVs are harder to parse correctly than you might think. Better to use the`csv` module. That's what it's there for.