# Saving a python dictionary (of lists) in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

A python dictionary (of lists)  can be saved in a CSV file as answered in the post available at [Write dictionary of lists to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613426/write-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-file).

The answer is as follows (directly copied from the above post),

```
d = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [4,5,6], "key3": [7,8,9]}
with open("test.csv", "wb") as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerow(d.keys())
   writer.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

How can we achieve the same task when the lengths the of lists available in the dictionary are different as follows,

```
d = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [5], "key3": [6,9]}
```

So that, it results in the following format (in the CSV),

```
  key1  key2  key3
   1     5     6
   2           9
   3
```

Comment: Using itertools.izip_longest?

Comment: @Useless Yep, that's a solution. But, aren't there any other direct ways to achieve this?

Comment: You're currently calling `zip`. You can change this to `itertools.izip_longest`. How many other ways do you want to achieve the same thing? You can easily write a loop explicitly, or write your own equivalent version of `izip_longest`, but ... why do you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `pandas` its very simple.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"key1": [1,2,3], "key2": [5], "key3": [6,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```