# How to save a dictionary with lists to a csv file

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary with two keys and a list with each key and was wondering how I could save the lists, with each key representing a column of the values within the list? The values are all Decimal('x') by the way.

An example of my dictionary is

```
mydict = {'Prices':[Decimal('1'),Decimal('2')], 'Quantities':[Decimal('4.3'), Decimal('2.2')]}
```

Overall goal is to save the dictionary and read in again to be back to how it was in another program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write dictionary of lists to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613426/write-dictionary-of-lists-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Why do you absolutely want csv? Why not simply using pickle?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to convert it into a DataFrame like so:

```
mydict = {'Prices':[1, 2], 'Quantities':[4.3, 2.2]}
#I didn't have the Decimal function defined.

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df.to_csv('save.csv')

#reading it in
read = pd.read_csv('save.csv')[['Prices', 'Quantities']].to_dict()
```